# Storing checkbox value in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I have a checkbox whose value `$row['uid']` I would like to store in local storage using javascript or jquery. When the user "unchecks" the checkbox, the value should be removed from local storage

This is my html:

```
<form> Favorites <input type="checkbox" class="favorite" value="'.$row['uid'].' onclick='.fave.add();'"></form>
```

This is what I have for the local storage in javascript at the moment. I'm not quite sure how I should add and remove the value `$row['uid']`

```
    var fave = fave || {};
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorite"));
    data = data || {};
            var fave = fave || {};
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorite"));
            data = data || {};
            $(function () {
                var data = localStorage.getItem("favorite");

                if (data !== null) {
                    $("input[name='favorites']").attr("checked", "checked");
                }
            });
            $("input[name='favorites']").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                localStorage.setItem("favorite", $(this).val());
                } 
                else {
                    localStorage.removeItem("favorite");
                }
            });
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "when the user refreshes the page"? Every time the page loads the value is going to be stored in the local storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` has two main functions, `getItem` and `setItem`. For `setItem` you pass in a key and a value. If you write to that key again, it will rewrite that value. So in your case, if a box is checked you would do `localStorage.setItem("checkbox_value", true)` and when it is unchecked you would pass in `false` instead. To get the value you can look at using jQuery like so: `$(checkbox).is(':checked')` and use a simple if-else clause to pass in true or false. then when you reload your page, on `$( document ).ready()` you can get the values using `localStorage.getItem(key)` and use Javascript to set the check boxes values.

This is how i would go about using localStorage to remember check box values.

Hope i helped! Ask me if anything is unclear.

Comment: thanks for the help! Assuming that I want to store all the different values of checkboxes that are checked, how should I do that? I've added a snippet of code above

Comment: localStorage only allows you to store strings. so what you can do is use a loop to create a string that has all the check boxes values separated by some delimiter. so for example if there are four check boxes with values true false false true your string would be `"true\nfalse\nfalse\ntrue"` where `\n` is the delimiter. then you can store that string in localStorage and when you retrieve it you can put all the values into an array like so: `array = localStorage.getItem(key).split('\n')`. Then you can populate your check boxes with that newly retrieved array. ask if anything needs clarification

Comment: thanks-does the edited code that I've posted above make sense, given that `$row['uid']` is an int?

Comment: yes your in the right direction. but i'm not sure why you call removeItem if the check box is not checked. wouldn't it be better if you set a different int? like 1 = checked and 0 = unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/Nq7xd/) to get you headed in the right direction:

```
var boxes, arr;

// This function loads the array and then checks the uid of each checkbox
// against it.

function checkBoxes() {
  arr = loadBoxArray();
  $.each($('input[type=checkbox]'), function (i, el) {
    if (arr.indexOf(i) > -1) {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
}

// If the localStorage item is available, load it into an array
// otherwise set a default array and save it to localStorage

function loadBoxArray() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('boxes')) {
    arr = loadBoxArray();
  } else {
    arr = [0, 2];
    saveBoxArray(arr);
  }
}

// Save the array to localStorage    

function saveBoxArray(arr) {
  localStorage.setItem('boxes', JSON.stringify(arr));
}

// On page load check the boxes found in localStorage

checkBoxes();

// Clicking a checkbox will update the checkbox array which is then saved to localStorage

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
  var arr = $.map($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function (el) {
    return $(el).data('uid');
  });
  saveBoxArray(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the check box state to persist after page refresh and if you don't mind using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/9L2Ac/

```
$(function () {
    var data = localStorage.getItem("favorite");

    if (data !== null) {
        $("input[name='favorites']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }


});



$("input[name='favorites']").click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        localStorage.setItem("favorite", $(this).val());
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("favorite");
    }

});
```

Comment: does this work if I have multiple values that I want to store in localStorage? the function unfortunately doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify(obj) for that.

Comment: You can also store each value in a separate slot (by checkbox name or id)